# Windows Azure Pack - Where's the Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-pack

Does anyone know if Windows Azure Pack is expected to offer the Storage service any time soon?  I have a client who's very interested in the technology, but only if it has storage....

Comment: This is a product-specific roadmap question.

Comment: You can develop you own extensions on azure pack, if thats something you would be willing to do:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn448721.aspx , for example you may use QNAP storage on in your datacenter and abstract its apis (http://www.qnap.com/dev/uk/p_api_sdk.php) using Azure Pack Extensions. It really depends on your situation/ if MS will implement this / ROI of dev investment.

Comment: I have already created my own "storage" library.  With that said, out of the box storage is a big part of the generic Azure offering so it would be great if they added it...

Comment: Azure stack should have storage. Don't know about Azure Pack

Answer (score 0):

**I have been tracking this thread for a long time, I have a good article about the feature in Azure Stack Preview release,
https://azurestack.eu/2015/06/microsoft-azure-stack-storage-explained-part-i/**

It is a good read on what to expect and how to prepare for the Azure Stack Storage. I am for one very excited about this feature as it will surely bring down the cost of maintaining tons of HA file servers for each team. Having a self service portal for secure HA file management on on-premise should put a smile on a lot of IT Admins!.

Hope the answer helps, **Please take a look at the Article. It is not for the faint of heart as it is very deep and heavy :), but worth the pretty pictures.**

**Happy to help !, yours truly - CB**